# iOS AdHoc OTA Distribution - Do I need to rebuild and redistribute every time I provision a device?

Tags: ios, distribution, ios-provisioning, ota

We have an in-house iOS app that we use for quickly entering time into our time system. It's hosted on an external facing site so that our users can simply point their phone browser to the app to download and install it over the air.

The question I have is this: If I build the .ipa with the OTA Distribution profile we've set up and deploy it to the site for download, do I need to rebuild and redeploy (or at the very least, re-sign) every time I add a new device to that provisioning profile?

Note: We have a 100 device limit

Comment: Yep.  I do this all the time, and then notify only the beta testers who are new, the rest see an update if they check tho, but I only email them if there is something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it truly is an Enterprise build, as in the Enterprise iOS Developer program, then you don't need to add any devices to it at all. You just need to create the provisioning profile once, and it will be valid for a year.

If it's just a normal Developer program, and you're building an AdHoc distribution - with 100 device limit, then yes.... you will need to rebuild the app every time you add a new device.

Comment: We are facing the 100 device limit, so I guess we don't have the Enterprise program... I'll rebuild and get back to you. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you actually still see the 100 device limit in the provisioning profile page, even when you have the enterprise program. You'll know it by what you paid for it. The normal program i $100 and the enterprise is $250 (last time i looked). If you go to Member Center >  Programs and Add Ons, it will tell you which one you have.